# Get only internal links and external from array (RegEx and PHP)

Tags: php, regex

This is my array output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com/some-page/
    [1] => http://www.example.com/another-page/
    [2] => http://www.example.com/third-page/
    [3] => https://www.example.com/ssl/
    [4] => https://www.example.com/with-slash-at-the-end/
    [5] => https://www.example.com/without-slash-at-the-end
    [6] => /internal-link
    [7] => /anther-internal-link/
    [8] => https://www.my-own-domain.com/internal-link-too-but-with-absolute-path/
)
```

How can I get only external and only internal links from this array? I doesn't matter which one.

Comment: Define `internal` and `external` link

Comment: @rock321987 If your domain is my-own-domain.com and every single link that will open a page within my-own-domain.com is an internal link. In my case, internal links are [6, 7, 8]. If you link google.com, yahoo.com, bing.com on your website (my-own-domain.com) that is an external link. Thanks.

Comment: So `example.com` is external link?

Comment: Yes, example.com is an external link.

Comment: Check this :- https://regex101.com/r/yK5zK9/2

The three highlighted links in last are `internal`..Is it ok??

Comment: This is the exception: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '|'

Comment: Its working fine..check :- http://ideone.com/zoUyVF

Answer (score 1):

This regex seems to work fine for finding `internal link`

```
(.*my-own-domain\.com.*)|(^\/.*$)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK5zK9/2)**

*PHP Code*

```
$re = "/(?:.*my-own-domain\\.com.*)|(?:^\\/.*$)/m";
foreach($str as $x) {
   if (preg_match($re, $x)) {
      echo $x . "" . "\n";
   }
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/zoUyVF)**